# There is an interesting problem. I'm using Laravel 8 and I'm getting this error from the passport: install command, I couldn't solve it

Tags: laravel-passport, laravel-8

Type of Laravel\Passport\Client::$casts must be array (as in class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your IDE may have overridden type casts - just re-install with composer require laravel/framework to fix